# How to use HTTP POST with "application/octet-stream" in Android? (Microsoft Cognitive Video)

Tags: android, azure-cognitive-services

I want to use the Video Cognitive Service in Android.
The sample that Microsoft provided is used in C#.
The video function is sending an URL to the server,
So I think it is possible using HTTP POST to send an URL in Android.

http://ppt.cc/V1piA

The problem I met is that I don't know the URL format in "application/octet-stream", and I didn't see the example on the Microsoft website.

Is it possible using HTTP POST in Android to upload a downloaded video to the server, and I can get the analysis result from the server?

If possible, what is the format of the HTTP POST to send request to the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may try something like this to send image files for cognitive-services face detect.
Using org.apache.httpcomponents::httpclient :

```
    @Test
    public void testSendBinary() throws MalformedURLException {
        File picfile = new File("app/sampledata/my_file.jpeg");
        if (!picfile.exists()) throw new AssertionError();


        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        try {
            URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect");

            builder.setParameter("returnFaceId", "true");
            builder.setParameter("returnFaceLandmarks", "false");

            URI uri = builder.build();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "***");

            // Request body
            request.setEntity(new FileEntity(picfile));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP POST refers to the [HTTP method 'POST'](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5), [application/octet-stream](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream) refers to the media type - in this case a stream of application specific octets or bytes.

This is, unfortunately, very subjective as the mechanism for uploading content via HTTP action may be preferred one way or another.  Suffice it to say, you will create an InputStream of your content, format a POST request using the mechanism of your choosing:

- [straight Java](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)
- [HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html)

Making sure to set the content-type of the POST to application/octet-stream.

After performing the post, consult your API documentation for expected return types.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I know how to send a URL to the server, but I don't know the format that Microsoft server wants when I want to upload a downloaded video by HTTP POST in Android.

Comment: I would surmise, based on the fact that they are requesting application/octet-stream, that they will apply a heuristic to determine the actual content of the stream. That media type is a blanket catch-all for any content that will transferred in an 8-bit pure fashion.

Comment: Looking at the request information it looks like you can get away with passing request parameters using ? on the URL then just send the body as application/octet-stream (i.e. send the stream as is)

Comment: The accepted input formats are covered [here](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/565d6516778daf15800928d5/operations/565d6517778daf0978c45e39).  The crucial info: MP4, MOV, or WMV, with an upper limit of 100MB