# How to upload Image to server from android retrofit

Tags: c#, android, web-services, wcf, retrofit2

Still looking for solution. Anyone know how to do this

I am uploading image from mobile to service. I uploaded image successfully but dont know how to save

I am using `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'`

retrofit method

```
@Multipart
@POST("RestService/json/PostKYCDocImg/")
Call<UploadPictureResponse> getURLKYCDocImg(@Part MultipartBody.Part imageData);
```

in android uploaded file by

```
File file = new File(new URI(de.getAttachFilePath()).getPath());
RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), mFile);
Call<UploadPictureResponse> call = apiService.getURLKYCDocImg(image);
```

In Wcf webservice i am receiving by

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/json/PostKYCDocImg/", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
[FaultContract(typeof(ServiceData))]
string UploadPicture(Stream imageData);


public string UploadPicture(Stream imageData)         
{   
   //saveImgInSpecPath(fileFullPath, GetBytesFromStream(imageData, 
   //System.Text.Encoding.UTF8), imageData); 

   saveImgInSpecPath2(fileFullPath, imageData);
}

private static Boolean saveImgInSpecPath2(string fileFullPath, Stream imageData)
{
   try
   { 
       //Save image here which is in imageData as stream and return saved status
       //var fileStream = File.Create(fileFullPath);
       //imageData.CopyTo(fileStream);

        //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(imageData.InputStream);
        //var fileStream = File.Create(fileFullPath);
        //imageData.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        //imageData.InputStream.CopyTo(fileStream);  

        //here i want to save image file which imageData in the form of stream

       bool exists = File.Exists(fileFullPath);
       return exists;
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
           return false;
    }
}
```

I tried lot of code in "saveImgInSpecPath2" method, all codes are uploaded to service path successfully but saved wrongly

> please suggest right way to save in wcf webservice from android
>   retrofit

Comment: `but when i open image`. It is totally unclear where, how and with what you try to open an image on a webserver. What did you tell Windows Photo Viewer?

Comment: for testing purpose i hosted web service in my system, when i go to that image path saved but i cant able to see that image when i open

Comment: Does byte[] has an overload of CopyTo which writes to a stream? You are sending both the stream and the bytes of the stream together into your method. If it is the stream you are invoking the CopyTo method, then the stream is exhausted and zero bytes will be copied

Comment: Well tell exactly what that path would be. And have you checked with Explorer if the file is there? What is its size? Equal to original?

Comment: Is this the actual code?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes this is actual code

Comment: Does byte[] has an overload of CopyTo which writes to a stream?

Comment: @OguzOzgul sorry i dont know that what you asking. you want to see GetBytesFromStream this method?

Comment: In the saveImgInSpecPath method, the line imageData.CopyTo(fileStream); seems invalid to me, because imageData is of type byte[], and Array does not have an overload of CopyTo which writes into a stream (unless you have an extension method)

Comment: any one know how to do still looking for an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in my project. And it works correctly.

```
Stream str = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\a.asadi\Pictures\Capture.PNG");
FileStream fs = File.Create(@"C:\Users\a.asadi\Pictures\test.PNG", (int)str.Length);
byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length];
str.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: i will check and come

Comment: fs.WriteByte(memoryStream) this line have Error 9 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.MemoryStream' to 'byte'

Comment: I've edited this code, check out. and change the 'str' with your stream.

Comment: in Second line got Specified method is not supported exception.

Comment: The exception that is thrown when an invoked method is not supported, or when there is an attempt to read, seek, or write to a stream that does not support the invoked functionality

Comment: how to overcome that issue

Comment: Your content type isn't  "application/octet-stream", I think this reason related to your exception.

Comment: Check out the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099028/how-to-use-http-post-with-application-octet-stream-in-android-microsoft-cogn)

Answer (score -1):

```
// retrofit method APIgetpost(interface java class)


 @Multipart
   @POST("RestService/json/PostKYCDocImg/")
   Call<UploadPictureResponse> getURLKYCDocImg(@Part@Part MultipartBody.Part 
   file1);
```

**//java class:**

```
public void ProfileupdateExecute() {
  ApiGetPost service = ApiConstant.getMainUrl().create(ApiGetPost.class);

      JSONObject jTestObj = new JSONObject();
      if (mediaPath != null) {
          strImgaepath = mediaPath;
      } else {
          strImgaepath = "";
      }

      //File creating from selected URL
      File file = new File(strImgaepath);

      RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

      userimage =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), requestFile);


       try {
       //photo field name

       jTestObj.put("photo", strImgaepath);

       } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }

       updatecall = service.ProfileUpdate(userimage);


    updatecall.enqueue(new Callback<UpdateTeacherProfileModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UpdateTeacherProfileModel> call, Response<UpdateTeacherProfileModel> response) {

                viewDialog.hideDialog();

                if (response.body()!= null) {

                    UpdateTeacherProfileModel userupdate = (response.body());
                    String Success = userupdate.getSuccess();

                    if (Success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileView_Activity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileView_Activity.this, "Check your credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UpdateTeacherProfileModel> call, Throwable t) {
                viewDialog.hideDialog();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                call.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
```