# How to send request upload file with Binary type using JAVA Rest Assured API

Tags: java, upload, rest-assured

Using JAVA with Rest Assured library, i am trying send a request to upload file using Binary type.

I found a lot example for using form-data type but no one for binary type when upload file.

Could someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need binary type? Any specific reason?

Comment: i'm implementing java code to send request api. I use upload file request of  Dropbox api: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

Comment: Why can't use you `x-www-form-urlencoded`? Why do you require `binary`?

Comment: Could you help to upload a file use "x-www-form-urlencoded". I use binary because the dropbox document api suggest uploading a file using binary

Comment: If the API expects a binary octet steam, then you may need to read the excel file first, convert it to bytes and then send those bytes using the API.

Comment: its perfect  if you have some example for using JAVA to code a request using binary type. Could you help bro?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40099028

Comment: Sample code here: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/4eeb3d82b1d4672787b57ca45167a63085c8c1f1/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/FileUploadingITest.java#L89

Comment: Thanks lucas, but unfortunately, having a error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to encode /D:/test.xlsx as a byte stream.

Comment: Can you update your attempted code to your question? I wanna see what you've already tried.